# What is the definition for "Publish" tags?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I just ran across a question with the tag [publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing), and saw that there are three other similar tags containing "publish": [publish](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publish), [code-publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-publishing), and [content-publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-publishing). None of them have tag wikis. I am not certain of the meaning for those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drupal, publishing is generally referred to nodes, which can be published (visible to all the users), or unpublished (visible only to users with the permission to administer content). [content-publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/content-publishing), [publish](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publish), and [publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/publishing) are then synonyms, and should be set as tag synonyms.

[code-publishing](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-publishing) seems used to refer to pushing/controlling code using a versioning system (e.g. CVS, Git), but for that there is already [version-control](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/version-control).

Comment: In your answer you state that they should be set as synonyms. How does one go about that?

Comment: Users with enough score for a tag can suggest tag synonyms that other users can vote. I don't have enough score for [tag:publishing] or [tag:version-control] to suggest synonyms, or vote them; the same is true for you. Moderators can create a synonym, if there is the need. A synonym is not created because a single user keeps using a tag instead of another; so far, the non necessary tags have been deleted; if users keep using the wrong ones, the moderators could do something.